# Convert “PDF” decompressed GZipStream to “PNG” C#

Tags: c#

I’m requesting from amazon shipping labels, and they sending back a string which is a compressed “GZIP” file, and I have to save it as “.gz” extension and then I can decompress it (Or Extract it), sometimes is the string in a “PNG” format and some is it a “PDF” format!
But I want to printout every time in a “PNG” format, but I cannot convert the decompressed (GZIPSTREAM) file to a “PNG” when they sending back a “PDF” format! 
is any help without to install third party libraries?

Here Is My Code

```
    public async Task PrintLabel(string imageLabelString)
    {
        var byteStream = Convert.FromBase64String(imageLabelString);
        GZipStream gzip = null;
        Image image = null;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteStream))
        {
            image = null;
            //File.WriteAllBytes("temp.gz", byteStream);
            using (gzip = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                image = Image.FromStream(gzip);
            };

            memoryStream.Position = 0;


            image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);

            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.PrintPage += (object o, PrintPageEventArgs e) =>
            {
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 750);
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(image, rectangle);
            };

            pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "PrinterName";
            pd.Print();
        }
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: This is non-trivial without a 3rd party library.  There are many hits for *c# pdf to image*

Comment: You can detect if the decoded stream is a PNG by checking the first 4 bytes.  In a PNG they will contain the string "PNG" in ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect a PNG by looking at the first 4 bytes of the stream.  PNGs have a marker that can easily be detected.

```
bool IsStreamPng(Stream s)
{
    s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); //Go to the start of the stream
    var headerBytes = new byte[4]; //Create a buffer to hold 4 bytes of data
    s.Read(headerBytes, 0, 4); //Copy 4 bytes of data to the buffer

    var headerString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(headerBytes); //convert the buffer to a string
    return headerString.ToUpper().EndsWith("PNG"); //do the first 4 characters of the header end with "PNG"?
}
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#5PNG-file-signature

Comment: Thanks for the response!
 But the hard thing is that even I know it’s a “PDF” I still cannot convert my “PDF stream” to a PNG stream so I can print it out as image!   Any solution? 
Thanks!

Comment: Ahhh, sorry, I misunderstood your question. I thought you only wanted to display PNG and needed a way to detect them. Unfortunately, I don't know of any way of converting a PDF to an image without 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Thanks anyway it's also very useful !

Answer (score 0):

...to improve upon @Bradley's solution to avoid unnecessary allocations:

From http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html

> The first eight bytes of a PNG file always contain the following (decimal) values:
>
> ```
> 137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10
> ```

```
public static Boolean IsPng(Stream stream) {
    
    // assuming stream is at position 0
    
    return
        stream.ReadByte() == 137 &&
        stream.ReadByte() ==  80 &&
        stream.ReadByte() ==  78 &&
        stream.ReadByte() ==  71 &&
        stream.ReadByte() ==  13 &&
        stream.ReadByte() ==  10 &&
        stream.ReadByte() ==  26 &&
        stream.ReadByte() ==  10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you respond! but again as i told @Bradley's  the hard thing is that even I know it’s a “PDF or PNG” I still cannot convert my “PDF stream” to a PNG stream so I can print it out as image! Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: @cmark Use a PDF rendering library. https://www.google.com/search?q=pdf+rendering+library